# Wordpress Permalink Redirect 301

Tags: permalinks

```
<?php
$permalink = get_permalink( $id );  
header("Location: ".$permalink, true, 301);
?>
```

Iam redirecting the URL without the id to id with 301 this php code is giving me problems, is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use php `header` function it will cause problems within wordpress.

Wordpress has its own function to make redirects

Function Reference: [wp_redirect($url, $status_code);](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Try this:

```
<?php
$permalink = get_permalink( $id );  
wp_redirect($permalink, 301);
exit;
?>
```

**Updated:**

I've worked out some code for you

Place this below code to your `functions.php` file:

```
function redirector($post_id) {
    if (is_single()) {
        $redirect_to = get_permalink($post_id);
        if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
            $ht_prot = 'http://';
        else
            $ht_prot = 'https://';

        $cur_link = $ht_prot . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $pattern = '/'.$post_id.'\/+$/';
        preg_match($pattern, $cur_link, $matches);

        if(sizeof($matches) < 1) :
            wp_redirect($redirect_to, 301);
            exit;
        endif;
    }
}
```

And call this function to your `single.php` file:

```
redirector($post->ID);
get_header(); ?>
```

Just before the `get_header();`

It will only redirect if you're in single post.

You can further change this code as your needs.

**Caution:**

If later you wish to change the permalink structure please remove the function call because it will continuously redirect and cause an redirect error.

Comment: I currenly have a URL a: /%postname%/%post_id% but even if i remove post-id the page loads i want to make it a 301 redirect to /%postname%/%post_id%

Comment: when i set custom permalink structure /%postname%/%post_id%/
it gives 404.
How actually its working for you and what do you mean by 'if i remove post-id the page loads'

Comment: For Example the URL: http://url.com/article-name/post-id, when i remove post-id the page has the URL like this http://url.com/article-name/. What i want if i remove post-id the URL should 301 redirect to this http://url.com/article-name/post-id and the page should not load without post-id in the URL

Comment: See my updated answer